# Why is the status of task inconsistent between logs and spark web ui?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I did the following operations on a rdd with 4 partitions in DStreams' foreachRDD function of my spark streaming application:

```
print rdd.count()
print rdd.collect()
```

The first statements `rdd.count()` is normally executed, while the second statement is always blocked by RUNNING status as the follow picture show:
[image]

However, when I take a look at the log, it shows that the task has finished.

```
18/11/09 16:45:30 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 3.0 in stage 26.0 (TID 555). 197621638 bytes result sent via BlockManager)
```

What's the problem?

The spark version is pyspark==2.2.1, cluster is spark on yarn.

Comment: What Spark version are you using? And what kind of cluster?

Comment: DStreams or Structured Streaming? What is the relation between the RDD and the stream?

Comment: I've added the information in the content of the question @BernhardStadler